# What are the jars necessary to bean validation?

Tags: java, jpa, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying validating my beans using bean validator. The problem is I don't know which libraries(jar) are necessary to validation.

I'm using.

Vaadin 7, BeanFieldGroup and EclipseLink

```
/** class of MyBean */
public class MyBean{
    @Id
@GeneratedValue 
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=5, max=50, message="Min = 5 and Max = 50, this field is not empty")
    private String name;

    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    private String email; 

}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: what build system are you using for your project?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Kepler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow these step-by-step instructions on how to download and configure Hibernate Validator in your Eclipse project:

1. Download the following Hibernate Validator files from JBoss Repository:

   - [validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central&g=javax.validation&a=validation-api&v=1.1.0.Final&e=jar)
   - [validation-api-1.1.0.Final-javadoc.jar](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central&g=javax.validation&a=validation-api&v=1.1.0.Final&e=jar&c=javadoc)
   - [validation-api-1.1.0.Final-sources.jar](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central&g=javax.validation&a=validation-api&v=1.1.0.Final&e=jar&c=sources)
   - [hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Final.jar](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central&g=org.hibernate&a=hibernate-validator&v=5.1.0.Final&e=jar)
   - [hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Final-javadoc.jar](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central&g=org.hibernate&a=hibernate-validator&v=5.1.0.Final&e=jar&c=javadoc)
   - [hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Final-sources.jar](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central&g=org.hibernate&a=hibernate-validator&v=5.1.0.Final&e=jar&c=sources)
2. Select your project's root in Eclipse
3. Go to **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries** view
4. Click **New...** button on the right to open **New User Library** window:

   - enter your library name (i.e. *Hibernate Validator 5.1.0*)
   - click **OK** button to accept
5. Click **Add External JARs...** button on the right to open **JAR Selection** window:

   - select the previously downloaded `validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar` and `hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Final.jar` files
   - click **Open** button to add them into *Hibernate Validator 5.1.0* library
6. Select **Source Attachment** under `validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar` tree node
7. Click **Edit...** button on the left to open **Source Attachment Configuration** window:

   - select **External location** radio button
   - click **External File...** button to open **JAR/ZIP File Selection** window
   - select the previously downloaded `validation-api-1.1.0.Final-sources.jar`
   - click **Open** button to set up **Location path** in the parent window
   - click **OK** button to accept
8. Select **Source Attachment** under `validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar` tree node
9. Click **Edit...** button on the left to open **Javadoc For 'hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Final.jar'** window:

   - select **Javadoc in archive** radio button
   - select **External File...** radio button
   - click **Browse...** button to open **Javadoc Archice Selection** window
   - select the previously downloaded `validation-api-1.1.0.Final-javadoc.jar`
   - click **Open** button to set up **Archive path** in the parent window
   - click **OK** button to accept
10. Repeat steps 6-9 for `hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Final.jar`
11. Click **OK** button in **User Libraries** view.

In a moment Eclipse is ready to work with Bean Validation constraints.

In fact you could end up the configuration on step 5) as this is all you need to make Bean Validation work, however development is much more comfortable if a given main .jar is associated with its corresponding -javadoc and -sources libraries as it gives you opportunity to:

- view Javadoc comments - <kbd>F2</kbd>
- view source files - <kbd>F3</kbd>

respectively for the selected constraint in Eclipse Java Editor.

---

Now, imagine you can achieve the same with a single step (well, almost) using Maven but that's another story for another time...

Comment: +1 for mentioning Maven. It is SERIOUSLY worth the small learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a few factors but the best you can do is to look for a README.md file inside the archive you downloaded. In my case that was hibernate-validator-5.4.0.Final.jar from the JBoss site. 
In there, among other things there's a section called "Using Hibernate Validator"

> ### Using Hibernate Validator
>
> In case you use the distribution archive from the download site, copy ***dist/hibernate-validator-<version>.jar***
>   together with all jar files from ***dist/lib/required*** into the classpath
>   of your application. For the purposes of logging, Hibernate Validator
>   uses the JBoss Logging API,  an abstraction layer which supports
>   several logging solutions such  (e.g. log4j or the logging framework
>   provided by the JDK) as implementation. Just add a supported logging
>   library to the classpath (e.g. log4j-<version>.jar) and JBoss Logging
>   will delegate any log requests to that provider.

+1 for the other answer that teaches you how to create a user defined library so you can group those files neatly into one convenient bundle.