# BeanCreationException entityManagerFactory NoClassDefFoundError ValidatorFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

My project was running fine until I've added 'hibernate-validator' in my POM for using @Valid feature at REST request for @RequestBody objects.

I have a NoClassDefFoundError

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ValidatorFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 35 more
```

My POM is

[image]

The last line is the one which makes problems, I've tried with several versions without success

Comment: Could you refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637800/classnotfoundexception-javax-validation-validatorfactory

Comment: I have not explicit reference to validation-api, cleaning tomcat and restarting IDE didn't work either

Comment: you just need  validation-api jar

Comment: I think I dont need it, validation-api is referenced internally by  hibernate-validator

Comment: that's why you need it.  It is required. It contains the Bean Validation API, and Hibernate Validation is an implementation of this API.

Comment: Maven resolves internally that dependency

Comment: No, maven does not.

Comment: @BlackBishop it's required..Ye Win is right....check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22547291/4117061)

Answer (score 1):

add

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
       <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0.GA</version> 
    </dependency>
```

Comment: even op accept to add validation-api manually, another error will be occurs. because Hibernate Validator 5x is not compatible with validation-api 1.0.x

Answer (score 0):

Go to the .m2 repository and delete the folder under org/hibernate/ path.
Now clean the project and again build the project. This may work fine.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers solved my problem, so I've decided to develop my own validator

A new annotation interface

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD) //can use in fields only.
public @interface Required {

}
```

And a base class to extend all objects I need to validate (at spring REST @RequestBody)

```
public void validate(){
    Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Required.class)) {
            Object value;
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                boolean fail = false;
                value = field.get(this);
                if (value==null){
                    fail = true;
                }
                if (value instanceof String && ((String) value).isEmpty()){
                    fail = true;
                }
                if (value instanceof List && ((List<?>) value).isEmpty()){
                    fail = true;
                }
                if (fail){
                    throw new PreconditionFailedException("attribute '" + field.getName() + "' cannot be empty");
                }
            } 
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```